# Protect application that uses time from a website as license key

Tags: c++, data-protection, copy-protection

I've made a small C++ application I am selling. My problem is that people are trying to crack it often.

I know its really simple, but I wasn't aware people was interested in cracking and leaking what I made. I am giving out licenses based on a date in the future, e.g. `2023-12-18 19:51:49` (18th of December 2023). I am then taking the string string and RC4 encrypt it and base64 encode it. This results in some "license": `0qAhemNdtHL5zI3D+B8zx1/psQ==` they can insert into their config.

The small application then decodes and decrypts the "license" and parses the time. It then comepares with time-now, also from http://just-the-time.appspot.com.

A guy wrote me that he easily cracked it by just changing the time returned by http://just-the-time.appspot.com. How would you mitigate this? If I am looking at the local time on the PCs people may just easier adjust the time.

Hope someone can help or lead me into a direction where I can read about this subject!

Comment: *My problem is that people are trying to crack it often.* -- Be aware that there will always be cracks for software, regardless of how crackproof you may make it.  You can make things more tougher to crack, but that's about it.  Second, *the local time on the PCs people may just easier adjust the time.* -- unless the user is running your software on a throw-away computer or on a VM, changing the system clock on a PC can have bad side-effects on the person's computer.  For example, there could be other software installed that is "better" time-bombed than yours, making that software useless.

Comment: Would it be possible to demand that your app has access to the internet? It could then connect to your server and ask to validate the license (which could then be a UUID). You of course need additional security measures, like protecting the program from having its code altered or memory tampered with etc, but it could be a base.

Comment: I realize how right you are. I was also just hoping to make it hard enough, but apparently that time check I am making is just plain silly almost according to the guy that wrote me.
Perhaps I should add a local time check as well. I could then check if local time and just-the-time.appspot.com corrolates to some extend. Thank you for your input!

Comment: The entropy source of your algorithm shouldn't be so easily accessible to everyone. Time is not a good one. More over, you should bind the license on some hardware ID; that is, if possible use the physical MAC address of the network interface or the serial number of CPU/hdd/chipset...